# When is a group of order $27$ solvable?

Tags: group-theory

Considered the non-abelian group of matrices with multiplication
$$
S = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a &  b\\
0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. I have to show that $S$ is not solvable.

My approach: First I calculated $\mid S \mid = 27$. Then I used the fact that  $S$ is solvable iff $[S, S]$ is solvable. Then I caluclated $[S, S]$ which turns out to be a proper subgroup of $S$. Hence $\mid[S, S]\mid$ $= 9$ or $3$. Since groups of order $9$ or $3$ are always abelian, therefore $[S, S]$ is solvable and hence $S$  is solvable which is contrary to what I hoped to prove. So is the question given (in my algebra book) is wrong?

Comment: Groups of order 27 (or any prime power) are solvable.

Comment: Groups of prime power are even nilpotent.

Answer (score 2):

This group is solvable. Are you sure of your question ?

-First, as @ancientmathematician commented, all groups of order 27 are solvable.
Actually, every $p$-group is solvable.
Another way to see it is to use the amazing (but much harder) Feit–Thompson theorem which states that all groups of odd order are solvable.

-Now, here, your group is the classical Heisenberg group with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. It is an easy exercice to show that it is nilpotent, and even step 2 nilpotent. You actually made the computation of $[G,G]$ and proved it was abelian, because it has order 9, but you can always prove that $[[G,G],G]$ is trivial, even when coefficients are not in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: yes I am sure of the question. see https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Cuvf_z4dsuoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=gopala+krishnan+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBi7vYrq7dAhVKPo8KHaYxCjYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=gopala%20krishnan%20algebra&f=false page no 70.

Comment: although I too believe the answer is solvable

Comment: For p-groups, it's not too difficult to show that they are solvable, and you don't need to invoke Feit-Thompson.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. It is always a good idea not to use a hammer when you just want to kill a fly.